# Creating PHP Admin Script for only one user

Tags: php

I have a website which is a front end to a MySQL database. This data is also exposed via a web service (fur use in Android application).

Currently I am maintaining the data via PHPMyAdmin but this is cumbersome and not that "pretty".

I want to create an /admin module where I log in (against values in a PHP Varialbe or a MySQL table) and once logged in I can edit,delete,add data.

Questions:

1. Is it acceptable in terms of security to compare entered credentials against static variables? There will only be one user so I feel like it is overhead to create a table for members.
2. Any guidelines on going down this route?

Comment: if this admin module will be more convenient handling data for that admin than mingling inside that cumbersome phpmyadmin, then sure go for it

Comment: If you use the md5 hash of your password, you don't need the password in clear text in the source code. `if(md5($pwd)=="abf348754")`

Comment: @ByteHamster if you use md5 for this you are a fool

Comment: @Dragon Why? No one ever sees your source code. If someone looks on your screen while programming, it is not in clear text. Better than just comparing it to a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

consider looking at this manual for [encryption methods with php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php). My gut instinct is to make a user table, or at least a table with just the encrypted password in it, rather than just checking the variable against a value.

That being said, if you don't think anyone will really even consider trying to fool around with the system and get past it, you probably don't need to be this cautious. I've built a few front-ends as well as back-ends to communicate somewhat friendly with a database, and I've never experienced a considerable amount pressure on the security.

Hope this helps, if you have any questions about how I've designed the ones I've made, feel free to email me at spencer@codeshrub.com

Comment: It should be noted that storing the password (even as a hash) in the PHP code is less secure than storing it in a database (such as MySQL), as a malfunctioning web server code leak the code out, there's the possibility that a hacker could change the code, etc. Also, if you ever need to allow more than one user then its alot easier if you a user table instead of just a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why you couldn't do it this way, assuming you will always have just the one user. The main consideration would be if someone somehow got a look at your code, they would see the stored password. So, you could store it using `password_hash` to generate a one way hash, and then verify it with `password_verify`. Here's how I might do it:

Using [**password_hash()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), generate a hash:

```
// copy the hash output, then delete this code
echo password_hash("thepassword", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Then, in your code, store the hash:

```
// paste hash here
$passwordKey = '$2y$10$j33UPA7gNxSOBsXQcyquLOZRuO6X8k8hZOb1RA79iN8gLlqp9eIPO';
```

Then run [**password_verify()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check the user input:

```
if (password_verify($userInput, $passwordKey)) 
    echo "correct";
else echo "incorrect";
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/PknTI

Answer (score 0):

If phpmyadmin is installed at your server localy, than it is NOT securely at all

You can use any MySQL client that supports ssh connection. E.g. [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) for Mac or [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) for WIN.

Also, you can use basic [HTTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for you admin script. But, since it's very simple it's not protect you from bruteforce or password leaking, etc.

Anyway, if you prefer security you need to make your own authentication in PHP, You can use [this package](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry) for example. It is simple and has many security features